# Saving source code of webpage that needs login

Tags: c#, cookies, authentication, gmail

I understood how to login to Gmail using c#, but when I try to go to the webpage it does not recognize I have logged in to Gmail.

Overall, I need to login to Gmail, and then access a webpage once I'm logged in, and save its source code, all using c#, preferably without having to open a browser, just doing all within the c# application.

Edit: I have logged in to Gmail successfully. But when I then go to the website, it doesn't recognize that I'm logged in. I need a way to do it in the same session. I tried researching but couldn't understand how to do it.

Comment: What research or code have you done already?

Comment: I have logged in to Gmail successfully. But when I then go to the website, it doesn't recognize that I'm logged in. I need a way to do it in the same session. I tried researching but couldn't understand how to do it. @StuartL

Comment: @StuartL - why do you ask?

Comment: Logging into Gmail via your own code is not the same as logging into https://mail.google.com.  Nor will it give you access to the source code on https://mail.google.com.

Comment: You have to use the session cookie from the c# script in your browser to continue the session.

Comment: @JayMee If you read the page on how to ask a good question, the first thing it says is "Search, and research". To me, this question is asking for someone to write the code. I'm sure the question hasn't got 5 downvotes (at time of writing) for no reason.

The question says they have logged into Gmail, but when they go to the website, it doesn't recognize them. What website? If it is another Google site, then on the face of things, they are authenticated. If not, then we need to know what website. What code is being used to authenticate, maybe that is the problem but we can't see it etc.

Comment: @StuartL - fair point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't Download the source code behind gmail, that is must likely closely guarded for security reasons, you can maybe get a response and try to download a list of mails if you want to make a Outlook lookalike.

if you need it all in one session, you need to find a way to share that across programs, your C# app runs in a separate environment then a browser does and cannot inter act directly, this has to be done through a API, socket communication etc.

you can however if all you want to do is to access gmail through your own program add the Web-browser component, from the toolbox to your form. (if you have one)

this is just a blank space (looks like a giant text box) that web pages can easily be loaded into. No URL bar, no controls in any way just completely blank
and then control the pages though your source code.

but what i wonder is why do you what this, why not just make your browser log you in automatically ?

Answer (score -1):

To also use the same session in the browser you should transfer the session cookie to the browser. I don't know if this is possible. I don't even know if Gmail likes/allows this.

I would suggest you try something different (**not** trying to transfer sessions for example), like opening Gmail in the browser instead of your C# program.

You also can't download Gmail's source.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why he downvoted?
Constructive criticism wanted.